# Nodejs CRUD + Test using Postman

Tags: node.js, postman

[image: PRODUCT CREATE - Test 2 with console.log][Product create - Test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omiTy.png) I was able to create a category, however when creating a product i tested it out using postman and got error: "", then i added the code which requires all fields be present. They all were,except the message keeps popping up error: "All fields are required". I have tried all the below solutions and none of them worked for me any ideas?

```
const formidable = require("formidable");
const _ = require("lodash");
const fs = require("fs");
const Product = require("../models/product");
const { errorHandler } = require("../helpers/dbErrorHandler");

exports.productById = (req, res, next, id) => {
    Product.findById(id).exec((error, product) => {
        if (error || !product) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: "Product not found"
            });
        }
        req.product = product;
        next();
    });
};

exports.read = (req, res) => {
    req.product.photo = undefined;
    return res.json(req.product);
};

exports.create = (req, res) => {
    let form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.keepExtensions = true;
    form.parse(req, (error, fields, files) => {
        if (error) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: "Image could not be uploaded"
            });
        }
        // check for all fields
        const {
            name,
            description,
            price,
            category,
            quantity,
            shipping
        } = fields;

        if (
            !name ||
            !description ||
            !price ||
            !category ||
            !quantity ||
            !shipping
        ) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: "All fields are required"
            });
        }

        let product = new Product(fields);

        // 1kb = 1000
        // 1mb = 1000000

        if (files.photo) {
            // console.log("FILES PHOTO: ", files.photo);
            if (files.photo.size > 1000000) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: "Image should be less than 1mb in size"
                });
            }
            product.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.path);
            product.photo.contentType = files.photo.type;
        }

        product.save((error, result) => {
            if (error) {
                return res.status(400).json({
                    error: errorHandler(error)
                });
            }
            res.json(result);
        });
    });
};

exports.remove = (req, res) => {
    let product = req.product;
    product.remove((error, deletedProduct) => {
      if (error) {
          return res.status(400).json({
              error: errorHandler(error)
          });
      }
      res.json({
          "message": "Product deleted successfully"
      });
    });
};
```

Comment: https://github.com/osern/ecom-react Here is the full project and there are some missing semicolons ; but i fixed them and it still does not work

Comment: did you consider using [`joi`](https://github.com/hapijs/joi)

Comment: console.log(fields) in your backend, fast and check which fileds are coming empty , you need to debug man

Comment: lol your shipping is ```false``` that;s why haha, you need to work on that shipping payload lol

Answer (score 0):

why not console log on every req i.e for example

```
exports.productById = (req, res, next, id) => {
    console.log(req.body);
};

exports.read = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
};

exports.create = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
};

exports.remove = (req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body);
};
```

you will get a clear picture whether your request are actually received by your backend.

Comment: All i got was empty brackets and the same error. ill upload the image to show you

Comment: it means your backend is not receiving any data please check whether postman is firing the http request to the right url, especially the port on which the server is runining for example http:\\localhost:3000\read

Comment: I was able to create a category and it showed on the database, however when creating a product it just does not work. The server is running and db is connected and the url is correct. Just can't figure out why any of this is happening

Comment: This is not an answer. Please put such recommendations in the comments section.

Comment: What do you suggest i do for the problem that is?

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (
            !name ||
            !description ||
            !price ||
            !category ||
            !quantity ||
            !shipping
        ) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: "All fields are required"
            });
        }
```

you are sending shipping false from postman , obviously it will return that 400 status, make it :

````
 if (
            !name ||
            !description ||
            !price ||
            !category ||
            !quantity ||
           shipping!== true || shipping !==false //something like that(or use something from formidable)
        ) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: "All fields are required"
            });
        }
    ```
````

Comment: i tried your suggestion and it still gives error: "All fields are required"

Comment: then one thing just before this  if  condition , can you console.log(fields) ?

Comment: i did that and it showed on the cmd {  'name': 'Node car', description: 'My first car on nodejs', price: '2000', category: 'category id number', quantity: '5', shipping: 'false' basically showed the fields i wrote on postman

Comment: can you try remove just ths "shipping"  field from if () and re run the server.. just wanna be sure is something wrong with shipping as a boolean

Comment: it just showed the same thing just minus the shipping

Comment: leme download ur project and run on my laptop

Comment: github.com/osern/ecom-react  here it is

Comment: mine got created .. bro , i did nothing here is the image, https://ibb.co/CWcyGTC , this got possible when i did     "role": 1, there may be some wrong business logic, when it was 0 it said , admin resource denied,... everything seems fine , it works, i didn't change the validation check

Comment: That is exactly my problem is that i just can't seem to get it to work

Comment: what's the role for ?

Comment: 1 is an admin and 0 is a non-admin user. My user has a role of 1 and all i get is the same error. Did you do something differently ?

Comment: here's what i did: 1.) made the JWT_SECRET, added it ....2.) started the server, ....3.) sign up the user,... 4.) signin the user(got the cookie) .... 5.) set the token in header .... 6.) made the /product/create/:userid request ....didn;t work ( gave me error, admin resource denied..bla bla ).....7.) went to mlab, edit the role to ```role:1``` ....8.) sent the request again, product got created.. you said your user has a role of 1 , **but in DB it was 0**

Comment: btw your code in github isn't updated, anyways i have used this .create() code from your stackoverflow code in the nonupdated code that i have, just to make sure that we are in same page, **have you changed the role and tried** ?

Comment: Still did not work and i mlab now just redirects me to mongodb. anyway i have robo3t where i changed the role to 1(admin) but still give me nothing. Also how did you change it from mlab? could you post a picture. I know i am asking a lot but i think im close

Comment: When i run npm start it shows db  connected and the port is running. How did you connect it to mlab. I think my problem is mongodb atlas as i don't see any updates on my DB. I connected using Robo 3t where it is showing the users created. Just want to make sure i am not missing anything

Comment: here is the img of mlab https://ibb.co/x12HkYS, i just wanted to be quick so i created db on mlab rather than in mongo atlas

Comment: mongo atlas, sometmes gave me that issue as well, but belive me user got created, or else it won't show in robo3t ,as robo3t is connected to atlas

Comment: Yes it was. i got help to solve it.  I don't know why, but It got solved when i changed the name in models to something else label: {
            type: String,
            trim: true,
            required: true,
            maxlength: 32
        },                                  it worked and when i changed it back to name it was still working. Maybe the problem was due to npm formidable.

Comment: if (
            !label ||
            !description ||
            !price ||
            !category ||
            !quantity ||
          shipping!== true || shipping !==false
        ) {
            return res.status(400).json({
                error: "All fields are required"
            });
        }
Actually this was the problem now. When i remove it, the code works.....guess i have a lot of debugging to do :/

Comment: glad, i knew there was some problem with this if condition

Answer (score 0):

your problem is on setting content type in postman. you send form-data to the server but your server not decoded it. by default, your server gets x-www-form-urlencoded and if you set postman on x-www-form-urlencoded your problem is gone.
you must use form-data for upload file